# Trouble getting a function's output to print on a new page using flask

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

Ok, I've been trying to do this for almost 10 hours now, and I can't figure it out. I have a restaurant search app, which works when printing the output to the terminal, but I have no idea how to get it to print on a new page. This is what I have so far:

```
@app.route('/')
def results(area, rating, food):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('SRG.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute('SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE address LIKE "%%%s%%" \
        AND rating > %s-1 AND type LIKE "%%%s%%" ORDER BY rating DESC' \
        % (area, rating, food,))

    while True:

        row = c.fetchone()

        if row == None:
            break

        print 'Name:    ',row[1]
        print 'Rating:  ',row[3]
        print 'Price:   ',row[2]
        print 'Type:    ',row[4]
        print 'Website: ',row[5]
        print 'Address: ',row[6]
        print 'Subway:  ',row[7]
        print 'Phone:   ',row[8],'\n'

    return render_template('results.html', row=row)
```

Now, that part works and prints to the terminal. I have a problem printing it to an html page. This is the template that I have so far:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Here are your results</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Check out these restaurants</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for row in results %}
            <p>Name:    {{ row[1] }}</p>
            <p>Rating:  {{ row[3] }}</p>
            <p>Price:   {{ row[2] }}</p>
            <p>Type:    {{ row[4] }}</p>
            <p>Website: {{ row[5] }}</p>
            <p>Address: {{ row[6] }}</p>
            <p>Subway:  {{ row[7] }}</p>
            <p>Phone:   {{ row[8] }}</p>
        {% endfor %}


            <p><em>Sorry, no restaurants fit that criteria</em></p>

    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Could someone please help? I feel like it is something minor and it is driving me crazy! It would be the best Christmas present ever!

Comment: If you want a new page, do `import os;os.system('cls')` in your while loop for Windows, `os.system('clear')` for Linux.

Comment: Sorry, new page might not be clear. I want the results to print on an html template page.

Comment: change to `return render_template('results.html', results=[row,])`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing codes under your while loop with this:

```
results = c.fetchall()
return render_template('results.html', results=results)
```

Two fixes:

- You used `results` variable in your template, but you never had passed it to your `render_template` function.
- Print something to console are totally different with render something to browser, everything that will be displayed on your webpage will **only** be the `return` value of your view.